# Making filtered search results display more performant in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I am implementing a search field that is going to filter through a truly massive amount of Text in SwiftUI.

Pre SwiftUI I am used to having more control over how and when the view is built so I have been able to make adjustments to make the search bar feel performant.

I am not finding the ability to take similar liberties in SwiftUI. I tried debouncing the search term but even this isn't working well here. The app freezes for long periods of time. And I can't really get a reason why from the trace.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct IdentifiableString: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    
    init(_ string: String) {
        self.string = string
        
    }
    let string: String
}

class ObservableSearchTerm: ObservableObject {
    @Published var query = ""
}

struct ContentView: View {
    static func generateGibberishString() -> String {
        let numWords = Int.random(in: 10...40)
        var buildString = ""
        for _ in 0..<numWords {
            let numChars = Int.random(in: 3...12)
            let alphabet = "abcd"
            var buildWord = ""
            for _ in 0..<numChars {
                buildWord += "\(alphabet.randomElement()!)"
            }
            buildString += buildWord + " "
        }
        return buildString
    }
    
    @State var searchString: String = ""
    @ObservedObject var observableSearchString: ObservableSearchTerm = ObservableSearchTerm()
    @State var debouncedSearchString: String = ""
    @State var displayIDStrings: [IdentifiableString] = ContentView.text
    
    static let text: [IdentifiableString] = {
        var build: [IdentifiableString] = []
        for _ in 0..<90000 {
            build.append(IdentifiableString(ContentView.generateGibberishString()))
        }
        return build
    }()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(displayIDStrings) { text in
                Text(text.string).padding()
            }.navigationTitle("Test Search")
        }.searchable(text: $searchString, placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always))
            .onChange(of: searchString, { oldValue, newValue in
                observableSearchString.query = searchString
            })
            .onChange(of: debouncedSearchString) { oldValue, newValue in
                displayIDStrings = ContentView.text.filter({ string in
                    string.string.lowercased().contains(searchString)
                })
            }
            .onReceive(observableSearchString.$query.debounce(for: 1.0, scheduler: RunLoop.main)) { term in
                debouncedSearchString = term
            }
    }
}
```

Here is a sample project if you want to play around with it.

Comment: Switch ObservedObject to StateObject but with 90000 strings I would move to  database of some kind

Answer (score 0):

To improve the performance of the search results display,
you could try this approach, where you use your own search bar.
It is a lot more performant than `.searchable(...)`, but may not be enough for your purpose.

The example code uses the `.onSubmit` and a separate `SearchView`
to avoid refreshing the main view as the user type in the search bar.

This means the results are presented only on a
return press (.onSubmit). However you can customise this to search as the user type,
(replace searchTemp with searchString) in `TextField`), in this case the
keyboard response takes a hit at first, then seems to be more responsive.

Note it takes a while to load the app.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    static func generateGibberishString() -> String {
        let numWords = Int.random(in: 10...40)
        var buildString = ""
        for _ in 0..<numWords {
            let numChars = Int.random(in: 3...12)
            let alphabet = "abcd"
            var buildWord = ""
            for _ in 0..<numChars {
                buildWord += "\(alphabet.randomElement()!)"
            }
            buildString += buildWord + " "
        }
        return buildString
    }
    
    @State var searchString = ""
    //    @StateObject var observableSearchString = ObservableSearchTerm()
    @State var debouncedSearchString = ""
    @State var displayIDStrings: [IdentifiableString] = ContentView.text
    
    static let text: [IdentifiableString] = {
        var build: [IdentifiableString] = []
        for _ in 0..<90000 {
            build.append(IdentifiableString(ContentView.generateGibberishString()))
        }
        return build
    }()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(displayIDStrings.filter{searchFor($0)}) { text in
                Text(text.string)
            }.navigationTitle("Test Search")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                        SearchView(searchString: $searchString)
                            .frame(width: 300, height: 26)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    
    private func searchFor(_ str: IdentifiableString) -> Bool {
        return (str.string.lowercased().hasPrefix(searchString.lowercased()) || searchString.isEmpty)
    }
}

struct SearchView: View {
    @State var searchTemp = ""
    @Binding var searchString: String
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField(" Search", text: $searchTemp) // <--- try searchString directly
                .autocorrectionDisabled()
                .font(.system(size: 22, weight: .light, design: .default))
                .textFieldStyle(.plain)
                .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5, style: .continuous))
                .onSubmit {
                    searchString = searchTemp // <--- remove if using searchString in TextField
                }
        }
    }
}
```